# Why won't the surface i created load?

Tags: c++, eclipse, image-processing, sdl-2

I am having trouble trying to load my this .png image using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include<SDL_image.h>
#include<string>


SDL_Texture *LoadTexture(std::string filePath,SDL_Renderer*renderTarget)
{
    SDL_Texture *texture=NULL;
    SDL_Surface *surface= IMG_Load(filePath.c_str());
    if(surface==NULL)
        std::cout<<"Error1"<<std::endl;
    else
    {
        texture=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderTarget,surface);
        if(texture==NULL)
            std::cout<<"Error2"<<std::endl;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    return texture;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
//Initializing and loading variables

    SDL_Window *window=NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderTarget=NULL;
    int currentTime=0;
    int prevTime=0;
    float delta=0.0f;
    const Uint8 *keystate;
    SDL_Rect camerRect={0,0,222,290};

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    int data=10;

    window=SDL_CreateWindow("SDL CodingMadeEeasY Series", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,222,290, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderTarget= SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );

    SDL_Texture *texture=LoadTexture("spaceship_stock2.png",renderTarget);


    bool isRunning=true;
    SDL_Event ev;

    while(isRunning)
    {
        prevTime=currentTime;
        currentTime=SDL_GetTicks();
        delta=(currentTime-prevTime)/1000.0f;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0)
        {
            //Getting the events
            if(ev.type==SDL_QUIT)
                isRunning=false;
        }

        keystate=SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

        SDL_RenderClear(renderTarget);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderTarget,texture,&camerRect,NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderTarget);

    }
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderTarget);
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);

        texture=nullptr;
        window=nullptr;
        renderTarget=nullptr;

        IMG_Quit();
        SDL_Quit();



return 0;
}
```

Window Output: A black window of  correct size.

Console output: Error1

Errors: No other Errors relating within this project, just warnings due to un-used variables.

The compiler cant find my png file even though i have a copy of spaceship_stock2.png saved in the debug folder and a copy saved in the release folder. Debug is currently active and I'm using Eclipse Helios.

I Have included the library flags, and have set the correct path for both the library and includes.

This is a slight modification of CODING MADE EASY's code in [a tutorial for scrolling backgrounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1dw7L0nC6s&t=13s).

Comment: Where's your `IMG_Init()` call and verification that `IMG_INIT_PNG` is supported?  Why aren't you checking `IMG_GetError()` for additional failure information?  Verify that your process' current working directory is what you are assuming it is.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by saving a copy of the .png file inside the Overall project folder but outside of the debug and release folder. I normally copy and past files via the project explorer.  How do you check the working directory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code to compile and display the image just fine. The only things I changed were `<SDL.h>` to `"SDL.h"` and `<SDL_image.h>` to `"SDL_image.h"`.

Then to compile, I ran

```
c++ code_file_name.cpp `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2_image
```

on my Linux system.